# Indefinite flushInterval in iBATIS

Tags: ibatis

Does anyone know what the behavior of an iBATIS cacheModel is when flushInterval is left out, say if the cache type is MEMORY?  I'm hoping that it simply leaves the cached results in memory indefinitely.  I have a set of results that will never change without a server restart, and I'm hoping only to query for them once during the lifetime of the app.  I was thinking that if I left the flushInterval element off the cache map, this would work...but I can't find anything in the documentation to confirm that.

Comment: Josh, I don't know the answer, but your cache hit rate might easily get to over 99.9% even with a flushinterval of only 60m, so setting a flushinterval to infinity doesn't really help that much.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Ibatis source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.ibatis/com.springsource.com.ibatis/2.3.0.677/com/ibatis/sqlmap/engine/cache/CacheController.java) and the [Ibatis User Guide](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ibatis/binaries/ibatis.java/ibatis-3/ibatis-3-core-3.0.0-190/iBATIS-3-User-Guide.pdf)

If flushInterval is not set in the CacheModel, then it is set to NO_FLUSH_INTERVAL which -99999 and isn't a positive number of milliseconds like the User Guide recommends. With this setting the cache is only flushed by calls to statements (flush on execute) or explicit calls to the flush command if you are overriding Ibatis.

In order to get the behaviour you desire you will also need to specify a 
`<property name="Type" value="STRONG"/>` in your CacheModel , for more information see [here](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s08.html)
.